# Convert string 5'8'' to 5.677 in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate BMI(Body Mass Index) using Python where user inputs their height and weight. The user inputs the height as 5'8" or 6" or 6'1" which should be converted into feet like 5'8" should be converted to 5.667. Here's my code so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

W = input("Enter weight:") 
H = input("Enter height:")

W = int(W)

BMI = 703*W/H**2

print(BMI)
```

My question is how I do convert those inputted 5'8" to 5.667 and do the calculation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to do that. There are 12 inches in a foot - 5'8" is not 5.8 feet, it's 5.667 feet.

Comment: You may have thought of this, but a foot has 12 inches so you may end up with e.g. 5'11" as input.

Comment: hmm, then 5'11" is 5.11? Not right.

Comment: Also, [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Yea...My mistake I am going to edit the question. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood your homework, you need to convert feet and inches into inches. 5'8" should go to 68 in your formula. Here's what you want to do (doesn't do any format checking though, assumes xx'yy"):

```
H_feet = H.split("'")[0]
H_inch = H.split("'")[1].split("\"")[0]

H_inches = int(H_feet) * 12 + int(H_inch)

BMI = 703*W/H**2

print(BMI)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

# convert feet'inch" to decimal feet
def decimalize_feet(s):
    m = re.match(r'^(\d+)\'(\d+)\"$', s)
    if m:
        return float(m.group(1)) + float(m.group(2)) / 12.
    else:
        return None
        # or handle invalid inputs otherwise
```